# Symfony Doctrine Query: SELECT ALL depending on time difference

Tags: symfony, time, doctrine, date-difference

I am trying to create a query where Doctrine will select rows based on time difference determined by the value from a column.

There are these two columns:

**diff** (type=integer) - specifies number of minutes

**start** (type=datetime) - specifies starting time

Now I need a query that will select all rows where the time difference between the value in **start** column and actual current time is lower than number in **diff** column.

In other words the query should select all rows where date in **start** column is not older more than number of minutes in **diff** column.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use something like `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, NOW()) > diff`

> Documentation for TIMESTAMPDIFF : https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php

But I don't think you can use it directly on DQL, maybe create a native query : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql

Comment: It's also possible to add this function to DQL.
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html